# put brew install openconnect 403 ,How to install it?

Tags: homebrew

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Llvk.png)

```
brew install openconnect

==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gmp-6.2.1.arm64_big_sur.bot
#=#=-#  #

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
Error: Failed to download resource "gmp"
Download failed: https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gmp-6.2.1.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
```

Thanks ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and running `brew upgrade` fixed it.